# Batch file for windows to rename multiple folders using a fixed part adding progressive number

Tags: loops, batch-file, directory, rename

I have many folders in a directory which I need to rename with a fixed base name and a progressive number starting from 1 to infinite.

Path of folders have space and base folder is D:\Programmi Installati.

Example of folders to rename:

```
log_1
log_2
log_04-01-2019 15-15-11,51
log_01-01-2019 8-22-14,19
log_27-12-2018 14-23-18,28
log_aaaa
log_bbbb
log_5
log_6
log_02-01-2019 6-21-17,34
log_03-01-2019 21-18-16,22
```

Example of wanted folder names:

```
log_1
log_2
log_3
log_4
log_5
log_6
log_7
log_8
log_9
log_10
log_11
log_12
```

The numbers of folder to rename can be large, but the structure is the same.

I tryed more batch file but all fail when there are some folders with the wanted name (example log_5 or log_1)

The order is not important it is important that all the folders starting with "log" are renamed with an incrental number.

Code already tryed without success

```
:: 1 code
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=
for /d %%a in ("D:\Programmi Installati\log_*") do (
   set /a counter+=1
   ren "%%~fa" "log_!counter!"
)
pause
```

---

```
:: 2 code
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Counter=1"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "D:\Programmi Installati\log*" /AD /B /ON 2^>nul') do ren "D:\Programmi Installati\%%I" "log_!Counter!" & set /A Counter+=1
endlocal
pause
```

---

```
:: 3 code
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem | Folder Path & CD To Location
Set "Folder=D:\Programmi Installati\"
CD %Folder%

Rem | Get Raw File Name
Set "Number=1"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir "log*" /S /b /AD') do (

    Rem | Rename Folder || Raw Name - %%~n1
    rename "%%~nA" "log_!Number!"

    Rem | Add One To Number
    set /a "number+=1"

)

Goto :EOF
PAUSE
```

The codes over works only if there is no desired directory name in the directory otherwise do not rename folders.

Comment: You could rename to a different extension (or prefix with same length) and when finished remove **that** temporary extension.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but are folders not files and folders have not extension, if you can suggest a code to do this, thanks

Comment: All the working batches rename with counter to i.e. `log-!Counter!` and when done do `ren log-* log_*` so there aren't intersections with current numbers. Also folders **can** have an exension.

Comment: Thanks for idea but i have some difficulties to integrated this idea in the code

Comment: See my below answer which does less renames, just the ones not fitting your scheme.

Comment: Thanks i need to add the path of folders to rename in the code, the path have space "D:\Programmi Installati\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch works differently, it

- skips folders with the proper naming scheme (so they keep the number)
- increments a counter and fills in possible gaps

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\11\SO_54149437.cmd
@Echo off
Pushd "D:\Programmi Installati\" || (Echo couldn't change dir&pause&goto :eof)
set Cnt=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /B /AD log_* ^| findstr /iV "^log_[0-9][0-9]*$" '
) Do Call :RenInc "%%A"
PopD    
Goto :Eof

:RenInc
Set /A Cnt+=1
if Exist "log_%Cnt%" goto :RenInc
Ren "%~1" "log_%Cnt%"
```

The resulting names (there are only eleven, not twelve)

```
log_1
log_10
log_11
log_2
log_3
log_4
log_5
log_6
log_7
log_8
log_9
```

Comment: Thanks for code, where i can add in the code the path of folders to rename "D:\Programmi Installati\" ?